# how to solve this problem? Problem Arch LInx npm: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1:?

Tags: javascript, npm, archlinux

When I try to start npm or enter any command, it throws me this error. How can I solve it? I tried to install openssl by yay and pacman but nothing installs and does not solve. Suggestions ??

Error : npm: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have arch linux

I tried installing in the openssl dependencies or the one that mentions the error but I couldn't find any I think I didn't find it

Comment: Do you have anything extra in your Pacman config, like testing or community-testing? What happens when you run `sudo pacman -S openssl-1.1`?

Comment: @ZacAnger this happened : Processing package changes... (1/1) installing openssl-1.1 [######################################## #################] 100% :: Running the post-install hooks... (1/2) Arming condition Need update... (2/2) Updating executables in /usr/bin...